# Qualitative analysis of $\frac{dx}{dt}=e^x-\cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to do the qualitative analysis of the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=e^x-\cos(x)$.

I know I could draw the vector field of the slopes but other than that I don't know what else I can do.
It occurred to me to find the equilibrium points but it is not easy to solve the equation.
Other than that I don't know what else I could say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can't find the equilibrium points in closed form, but you can say there is one in various intervals due to the fact that $\cos(x)$ oscillates between $-1$ and $+1$.  These equilibrium points divide the real line into intervals in which $dx/dt$ is positive or negative...